# HTML - Change a value on a web page

Tags: javascript, html

Okay so here is a question I have looked online for a lot but I am not too sure which terminology can be used. I am wondering if I can make a simple html website which has a piece of text on it which any user can change. However, when this text/variable is changed I want it to stay like that and display like this for all users.

Sorry for not being too specific but I am not too sure what else to say.

Thanks :)

Comment: You want to add a server side script to the mix, something like PHP. Potentially some SQL to store the data.

Comment: _I want to make a free text sandbox anyone can edit_ Good luck with that

Comment: I know it sounds weird and I knew I would get grief for posting this, but there is some idea behind it...

Comment: What you're asking for is a wiki.  This has been done.  Often.  What do you think you have that will improve all the pre-built solutions?

Comment: I am basically asking what sort programming do these wikis use to achieve what the do? I would hopefully like to achieve this using javascript on my server and I am wondering if it is that simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at something like https://github.com/justjohn/editor5.  This uses `contenteditable` and like someone else said, you'll need something server side and somewhere to persist it (this uses PHP and Redis, respectively).  Good luck with your internet abuse engine!

Comment: Thanks for finding this for me  :D

Answer (score 1):

You will need host your webpage from a server that stores the data in a database or a file that exists on the server's hard drive. Html and javascript do not offer a way that you can store data such that any user that visits your page will see the changes made by other users. By storing your data in a centralized place (a database) and providing access through a server hosting your page you could achieve your goal.

Comment: Okay, I am sure there are many permissions stopping users from simply changing files on the server such as a text document. Are you saying it could be possible to have some sort of HTML input form which has permission to change the contents of a file?

Comment: You need to have some sort of API provided on a server. You can create a function in JavaScript that whenever the user hits a submit button it makes an Http Put request to the server and passes the new value that will be stored. Then set a listener on your server for that function, and whenever the API gets called your server updates the value stored in the file or database.

I'd suggest doing more research online, here is a link with some more information: http://www.restapitutorial.com/